# how to call selector in js $('.tncSelect').click(function() .. its working when i call alert?

Tags: jquery

```js
$(function() { //alert('hello');
  $('.tncSelect').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      var s = "=> " + $(this).val();
      document.getElementById('cntr-terms').value += s.substring(s.length - 500) + '\n';
      //$("#cntr-terms").val(s);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="optradio" id="someUniqeu" class="tncSelect" value="hello">

<textarea class="form-control" id="cntr-terms" rows="10" placeholder="الشرح ..."></textarea>
```

its working when i place alert(); before calling function... but its not calling without alert()..

Comment: When you include jQuery in the page (as I have edited your snippet to do) then the code appears to work fine as it is, without an `alert()`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks..i do the same but its not working on my localhost... $(function(){ } even after place alert() if i refresh the page then its call $('.tncSelect').click(function() {} otherwise no response..